# Stata 13 on Linux: how to deal with spaces in filepath using export delimited?

Tags: linux, stata

I'm running Stata 13 on a Linux system and am running into a problem when I use the `export delimited` command to create a file with a space in the filename. Even when I surround the filename with double quotes, Stata seems to see the space as the beginning of another argument, rather than as part of the filename. Here is my attempted command followed by the error message:

```
. export delimited "my file.csv"
invalid 'file.csv' 
                 stata():  3598  Stata returned error
export_delim_write_file():     -  function returned error
export_delim_export_file():     -  function returned error
                 <istmt>:     -  function returned error
```

My current fix is to use the `outsheet` command instead:

```
outsheet using "my file.csv"
```

I do not run into an error this way. However, it is my understanding that `outsheet` has been superseded by `export delimited` in Stata 13, so I would like to begin using the more up-to-date command.

Is `export delimited` supposed to deal with spaces in quoted filenames differently than earlier commands? Is there a way I can convince it to recognize spaces? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I can't test (no Stata 13 at hand). But I would advise against using `outsheet` since it respects the display format assigned to numerical variables (other than _datetime_ formats). This means you risk very imprecise values in the exported file. Assuming the space issue is really a bug, I would rather eliminate the space; use **_** or **CamelCase** or whatever else you like.

Comment: One report goes back to [2002](http://hsphsun3.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/lwgate/STATALIST/archives/statalist.0206/date/article-108.html). I confirm this behavior is still present in Stata 12.1.

Comment: This is identified as a bug fixed on 12 August 2013. So `update` your Stata 13.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thanks for the warning about `outsheet`.

Comment: @NickCox Ok, thank you, Nick. I'll work on updating my Stata. Unfortuantely I'm firewalled out of updating my Stata at work. So, here goes a conversation with IT.....

Comment: @SamLarson you may choose to update your Stata [manually](http://www.stata.com/support/updates/stata13.html) if firewall is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the file name in compound double quotes:

```
 export delimited using `"my file.csv"'
```

Additionally, is it absolutely necessary to embed spaces in the file name?  If you absolutely need to separate words in a file name and don't like lowerCamelCase, you could use underscores to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks, Billy. I did try the compound double quotes method. But this ended up being a problem that was fixed in a Stata update. Once I updated, the problem went away. I actually forget why I wanted spaces in the filename in the first place. Usually I like underscores. Who knows anymore. Cheers.